# Show hide in angularJS if not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, if-statement, show-hide

I have these two images

```
<img ng-show="cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI" src="{{cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI}}" />
<img ng-hide="cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI" src="/assets/img/placeholder.png">
```

**Problem:** If `{{cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI}}` not empty display first image else display second image. I use `ng-show`, `ng-hide` but not working.

**Not working means:** where `{{cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI}}` is not empty its also display second image, and where is `{{cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI}}` empty at that place its also displaying second image, but when I remove `ng-show` it display first image correctly.

Comment: Did you try using `ng-if`?

Comment: What is not working ? It is working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/70Rhng29h1LHIoYie5gT?p=preview

Comment: Did you check the example mentioned in the comments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code as follows:

```
<img ng-show="cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI != ''" src="{{cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI}}" />
<img ng-hide="cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI != ''" src="/assets/img/placeholder.png">
```

Give it a try.

Hope it works.!

Answer (score 1):

Something like,

```
<img ng-src="{{cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI? cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI : ('/assets/img/placeholder.png')}}"/>
```

It will help to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<img ng-src="{{cat1.PictureURIs[0].URI || '/assets/img/placeholder.png'}}" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  For example, it's not immediately obvious what the difference is in your answer.  You might want to explain `ng-src`.